# Can regions be printed within a node template?

Tags: theming

Can regions be printed within a node template, or are regions strictly confined to page templates?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can print regions inside any template, but they aren't available out of the box in the `node.tpl.php` template. To make them available, you'll create a new variable for use in your `node.tpl.php` template that'll contain all the region content.

Creating new template variables is done by using a preprocess function. In your theme's `template.php` file, create a function that looks like this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
}
```

Replacing `mytheme` with your theme's short name. Now, in order for Drupal to recognize this new preprocess function, you need to rebuild your site's theme registry. This is as straightforward as going to *Configuration* → *Development* → *Performance* and pressing the "Clear all caches" button at the top.

Now, the way preprocess functions work is that `$variables` contains an array that corresponds to your template's available variables. For example, in `node.tpl.php`, `$submitted` contains the author byline. In the preprocess function above, it's found in `$variables['submitted']`.

To mimick what you have in `page.tpl.php`, where you have an array called `$page` that contains all the regions, you'd want to populate `$variables['page']`.

The problem is that `$page` in `node.tpl.php` is already populated with a true/false value that lets you know whether you're looking at the node by itself or in a listing.

So to avoid that name collision, populate `$region` instead:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  // Get a list of all the regions for this theme
  foreach (system_region_list($GLOBALS['theme']) as $region_key => $region_name) {

    // Get the content for each region and add it to the $region variable
    if ($blocks = block_get_blocks_by_region($region_key)) {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = $blocks;
    }
    else {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = array();
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your theme's `node.tpl.php` template, you can render any region by doing the following:

```
<?php print render($region['sidebar_first']); ?>
```

Where `sidebar_first` is the name of the region you want to render.

Comment: Finally a working solution for Drupal 7 :)

Comment: There's also a quick 'n' dirty solution that worked for me `<?php print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('machine_name_of_your_region'));?>`. From here: http://www.webomelette.com/add-region-node-template

Comment: This solution is nifty. Could you give examples as to when is it most applicable to print regions within node.tpl.php instead of having it in page.tpl.php?

Comment: It depends on your design. Sometimes the layout might put the sidebar in a place where it is much easier to theme if it were inside the node div instead of outside of it.

Comment: Don't forget about appropriate region wrappers! See [system_page_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_page_alter/7) for reference. Remember that `block_get_blocks_by_region()` returns only array of blocks and if you want to render it as a region, you need to add region wrapper.