# Render a custom region inside node template

Tags: nodes, theming

I am attempting to render a menu assigned to a block right next to the body of a custom content type. I am using Drupal 7.

I have a custom region defined within my template `.info` file. I would like to render this region and the block assigned to it from within a custom node template ...

`node--<my custom content type>.tpl.php`

I needed to do this within the custom node template because I needed to break out the individual fields of the content type rather than just using

`print render($content);`

This is what I was trying to do ...

```
<div class="content">
  <?php
    print render($content['title']);
    print render($content['field_banner_image']);
    print render($content['body']);
  ?>
  <div><?php print render($page['MY-CUSTOM-REGION']); ?></div>
  <div><?php print render($content['body']); ?>div>
</div>
```

However, my menu block does not render and I get the following error ...

`Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in include()[PATH TO MY CUSTOM NODE TEMPLATE]`

Is it possible to render a region from within a custom node template?

Comment: I found a solution from http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20054/can-regions-be-printed-within-a-node-template. Basically I need to add a function to the template.php file for my theme. Once I did that the node tamplate was "aware" of my custom region and I was able to render it. The above article has a very thorough and detailed explanation.

Comment: could you post your solution as an answer and check it? it will hep others to identify quickly the solution :)

Comment: @cayerdis don't repost answers, mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should load your menu yourself inside node, use:

1. [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7)
2. [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)
3. hook_preprocess_node